# getchar_unlocked() slowing down execution time

Tags: c++

I was attempting a problem on CodeChef where the input will be an array of size N, and we have to output the number which repeats itself most in the array along with the count.

Problem link :: http://www.codechef.com/problems/MAXCOUNT/

I first wrote the code using scanf for input, and got an AC but the execution time(0.94s) was pretty near the allowed time(1s). I had read getchar_unlocked() significantly decreases the input time, and hence tried to implement it using getchar_unlocked. But instead it got me a Time Limit Exceeded error.

The code using getchar_unlocked ::

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

void fastRead(int* a)
{
 char c=0;
 while (c<33) c=getchar_unlocked();
 *a=0;
 while (c>33)
{
    *a=*a*10+c-'0';
    c-getchar_unlocked();
}
}

int main()
{
int cases;
int size,in;
fastRead(&cases);
while(cases--)
{
    int arr[100001]={0};
    int max=0;
    int index=0;
    fastRead(&size);
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        fastRead(&in);
        arr[in]++;
        if(arr[in]==max)
        {
            if(in<index)
                index=in;
        }
        if(arr[in]>max)
        {
            max=arr[in];
            index=in;
        }
    }
    printf("%d %d\n", index, max);
}
return 0;
}
```

Was there something wrong in the way I implemented to code?
Thank you!

Comment: I can tell you with absolute certainty that I/O functions aren't the problem here.

Comment: Yes there was. If you want to make your program run faster, use a profiler.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar : Then how can the same code with just the scanf() changed to fastRead() have different execution time?

Comment: show the code with the `scanf()`..

Comment: @WeaselFox: Kindly check my solution with scanf() at http://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/2581399

Comment: You might want to look up "trees", "hash maps" and "algorithms".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's your actual code, then

```
c-getchar_unlocked();
```

will cause an infinite loop since `c` is never modified.

I suspect you want

```
c = getchar_unlocked();
```

Using the space bar won't make your code run slower and makes the code more readable.

Comment: "Using the space bar won't make your code run slower" - epic.